# .Net 6 Deployment - Web Deploy cannot modify the file dll on the destination because it is locked by an external process

Tags: msbuild, webdeploy

I am running into the problem of my .Net 6 app publishing fails due to .dll being locked. I tried using an App_Offline file and ran into several issues:

1. This seemed needlessly complex to set up. Basically I had to use Powershell to copy an App_Offline file to my site, then deploy, then remove the file.
2. Even after figuring out how to make this happen (The app_offline file) the problem would still happen.

There must be a solution for this that doesnt involve manually stopping the site before every deployment?

I am deploying with MS Build:

```
MSBuild.ex MyProject.csproj /p:WebPublishMethod=MSDeploy /p:Configuration=Release /p:ProjectName=MyProject /p:PublishProfileRootFolder=${WORKSPACE}\\MyProject\\Properties\\PublishProfiles /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:PublishProfile=Develop.pubxml /p:WebDeployUser=${WebDeployUser} /p:Password=mypassword  /p:IgnoreDatabaseSettingOutOfSync=True
```

**UPDATE**

I added the parameter /p:EnableMSDeployAppOffline=true. I can see that this app_offline file gets created, but the process still sometimes fails with that same error. And when that happens, the app_offline file doesnt get deleted so my site is left in a broken state.